# Identify sql exception in c#?

Tags: c#

how to catch sql exception with its error code(error no) to identify which exception is exactly thrown in c# ?
for example  database is offline or there is reference row in other table so sql wont allow me to delete row but how exactly i could identify what is the problem in catch so that i can display message to the user in my application

Comment: What library are you using to interact with the db?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put your database code into a `try ... catch` block, and (assuming you're using ADO.NET against SQL Server) then catch the `SqlException`.

```
try
{
   // your database code here
}
catch(SqlException sqlEx)
{ 
   foreach(SqlError error in sqlEx.Errors)
   {
       // you can inspect the individual errors, their code etc. here
   }
}
```

The `SqlException` object will contain a collection of `SqlError` objects that describe the error that happened in great detail - with line number, error code and everything.

Other databases will have similar constructs - check your docs!

Answer (score 1):

There are specific numbers assigned to each type of exception in .net Exception class hierarchy you will find some useful material over [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/guys/archive/2005/05/20/408142.aspx)

Comment: Link returns "this page does not exist".